# mod_rewrite, subdomains and htaccess in CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, dns, subdomain

Right now i'm working on a webshop project in codeigniter.
In the end there will be multiple webshops on subdomains, and a frontpage on the main domain.

It's supposed to be all dynamic so that the webshops get their own subdomains.
The shop information is in the database. Lets say I have a mysql table which contains info like this:

- webshop:       Bobs shop
- webshop_subdomain:   bobsshop

And so on.

Now in a .htaccess file I want to make a rewrite rule so that bobsshop.mydomain.com will be rewritten to mydomain.com/bobsshop/ since i'm working in Codeigniter with controllers.

You should bear in mind that the index.php also has to be rewritten out and there should also be the possibility to make subpages like bobsshop.mydomain.com/contact/

I will make a php script which will check if the subdomain exists in the database and if it doesn't exist then the visitor will see a 404.

My DNS setup looks like this ATM:

- mydomain.com        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
- *.mydomain.com      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is my server IP.

I've really never worked with htaccess / mod_rewrite before.
Can it be done? And are there anyone who can help me make this?

Sorry for my English. I hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)(?!mydomain\.com)[^\.]+)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?/%1/$1 [L]
```

Input URL - http://adasd.mydomain.com/test

```
1    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)(?!mydomain\.com)[^\.]+)\.

     This condition was met

2    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?/%1/$1 [L]

     This rule was met, the new url is http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?/adasd/test
     The tests are stopped, using a different host will cause a redirect
```

Output URL - http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?/adasd/test

You can then remove the index.php from the URL by

1. Open config.php from system/application/config directory and replace
   `$config['index_page'] = "index.php"` with `$config['index_page'] = ""`
2. Implementing the above .htaccess file

In some case the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. To solve this problem just replace `$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"` with `$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"` in system/application/config/config.php

Comment: It doesn't seems to work.
It's supose to be a shop when you enter the subdomain.
Like a-shop.mydomain.com.
It doesn't work now.
If i type a-shop.mydomain.com it shows me the main page, which is suposed to be on mydomain.com.

Maybe i should mention that a-shop is a dynamic controller in codeigniter.

What about my virtualhosts file? Should i do some thing with that? And what about the DNS? Is that correct to?

Comment: When you say a dynamic controller what do you mean? The above .htaccess will send requests from a-shop.mydomain.com/foo/bar to mydomain.com/a-shop/foo/bar meaning that a-shop is the controller, foo is the method and bar is param 1. You needn't touch your virtualhosts or DNS settings they look fine.